# Js: How to reference> property constructor from another constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I want to reference a property in `Constructor1` (property1) from `Constructor2` 
and I thought, it was ok by doing this... or should I nest the `constructor2` inside the `constructor1`?

```
var Constructor2 = function() {
    this.method2 = function() {
        // how to reference Constructor1.property ???
    };
};

var Constructor1 = function() {

    this.property1 = true;
    this.property2 = false;

    this.method1 = new Constructor2();
};

var inst = new Constructor1();

inst.method1.method2();
```

Comment: Is `GForce` the same as `Constructor2`?

Comment: You need to pass the `inst` as an argument to the `method2`, or create a reference to it from the constructor of `method1`.

Comment: The method isn't on the constructor at all. It's on the instances that it returns. `this` doesn't refer to the constructor, but instead the object that will be returned when you call `new Constructor1()`.

Comment: yes I made a mistake GForce is Constructor2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems an example of the delegation pattern.

Your "class" Constructor1 is delegating part of its logic to the "class" Constructor2.

Constructor2 needs to access the properties of the delegator and this can be done passing an instance of the delegator to the delegate:

```
var Constructor2 = function(delegator) {
    this.delegator = delegator;
    this.method2 = function() {
        console.log(delegator.property1);
    };
};

var Constructor1 = function() {

    this.property1 = true;
    this.property2 = false;

    this.method1 = new Constructor2(this);
};

var inst = new Constructor1();

inst.method1.method2();
```

I think that it would be better to consider Constructor1 and Constructor2 not as constructors but as classes. I understand that they are functions and that they are used to create objects, but usually they get the name of the class they will instantiate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now Im gonna ask... is this a good way to do that? why not should put `Constructor2` inside `Constructor1`

Comment: I think that if Constructor2 lives only as part of Constructor1, it can make sense what you are suggesting.